# Unable to log in to Gmail account

Tags: gmail

I am having trouble to log in to my Gmail account on a Linux box (Ubuntu) in Firefox.

I get redirected to a page saying

> We are sorry, but you do not have access to Email. Please contact your domain administrator for access.

What the heck is going on?

[image]

Comment: Is this a personal account or a business account?

Comment: I want to log in to my personal account. But I cannot even open 'gmail.com' - I am redirected to that page ...

Comment: Are you logging in from work? They may have blocked access to Gmail at the proxy. (My employer does.) That certainly doesn't sound like a message that Google would give. Can you give a screen shot?

Comment: Screenshot added. And yes I am using it from work. Has worked the last five months without issues (and from google chrome as well thankfully!!)

Comment: Maybe I am logged in with my work account somehow and the company proxy make a redirect or something?

Comment: Clear your cookies and your browser cache.

Comment: That seems to have worked. But I was sure I did that already...

Comment: I have to clean browser cache at least every some hours....

Answer (score 3):

Late answer but if you try adding new users to G Suite, the new user will get that same error when attempting to access email.

This looks like a new development since users created in the past didn't experience the same issue

To resolve, just go to the admin console and manually assign a G-Suite license to the new user.

A user with a similar issue asked the question on this forum [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/116486/users-cant-access-gmail-accounts-in-g-suite) but unfortunately some busybodies closed the issue even before it was resolved.

Hope this will assist someone facing similar problem without having to waste a whole day as I did

Comment: Just in case someone lands here, licenses can be found after clicking the name of a person, on the bottom of the page