# Users can't access Gmail Accounts in G-Suite

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business

I am the Admin for the G-Suite Account. I am seeing the following in my admin (see below), but new users are getting ***"We are sorry, but you do not have access to Email. Please contact your domain administrator for access."***

Any suggestions?

[image: G-Suite Service Status]

Comment: Raise a support ticket.

Comment: Hi Gary, I think this is a good question, but there's not a lot to go on here.  Are there any other switches you've tried to flip?  Is there a billing issue, maybe?  Kevan has offered some suggestions, so perhaps try those and if they don't help, edit this information into the question so that someone has enough information to help you out.  Thanks!

Comment: Solution: Just in case someone lands here. Even though it's "On for everyone", new users won't have it on unless you manually do it (at least it happened to me), so I had to go to Users, open the user with the problem, and select the G Suite Basic license at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

While you have GMail turned on for all active users, have you actually added Active users and used the Admin system to send them login information?

Check Your Users section of your Google Admin center.
Check the list of Active users and make sure those accounts can be logged in.

If users are not listed there, check the Suspended Users list.